# SELECT / JOIN multiple tables and indicate which table a match was found in

Tags: mysql

**Scenario**

'addresses' = One huge table of addresses, includes postcodes (unique addresses but postcodes are one-to-many)

```
---------------------------
| ID | POSTCODE | ADDRESS |
---------------------------
```

'ZoneA' = table of Zone references and corresponding Postcodes (postcode is unique within table, but may appear in other 'Zone')

```
------------------
| POSTCODE | REF |
------------------
```

'ZoneB' = second table of Zone references and corresponding Postcodes (postcode is unique within table, but may appear in other 'Zone')

```
------------------
| POSTCODE | REF |
------------------
```

The postcode of an address may appear in one or both ZoneA and ZoneB.  To complicate things, I only need to match a subset of the references in each zone.

**I'm trying to return something like...**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| ID | POSTCODE | ADDRESS | ZoneA(Y/N) | ZoneB(Y/N) |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

(where y/n indicates that the address postcode appears in that zone table)

**What I have so far...**

```
SELECT addr.* FROM addresses AS addr 
WHERE addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT a.postcode 
    FROM ZoneA AS a
    WHERE a.zoneref IN
    ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4') 
)
OR addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT b.postcode 
    FROM ZoneB AS b 
    WHERE b.zoneref IN 
    ('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4')
)
```

Which gives me the addresses that have postcodes that appear in ZoneA or ZoneB, but doesn't show which zone they appear in - and I'm not convinced this will deal with addresses that appear in BOTH zones as theres no GROUP clause.

Any suggestions on how I can get this working, or do it better?

**** Sample Input/Output ****

Addresses

```
----------------------------------
| ID | POSTCODE | ADDRESS        |
----------------------------------
| 01 | SW1 ABC  | 1 Street, city |
| 02 | SW1 DEF  | 2 Street, city |
| 03 | SW2 ABC  | 3 Street, city |
| 04 | SW3 XYZ  | 4 Street, city |
| 05 | SW4 XYZ  | 5 Street, city |
```

ZoneA

```
------------------
| POSTCODE | REF |
------------------
| SW1 ABC  | A1  |
| SW2 ABC  | A1  |
| SW3 XYZ  | A2  |
```

ZoneB

```
------------------
| POSTCODE | REF |
------------------
| SW1 ABC  | B1  |
| SW1 DEF  | B1  |
| SW4 XYZ  | B2  |
```

Output (for example, 'ZoneA.ref IN (A1, A2) OR ZoneB.ref IN (B1)'

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 | ID | POSTCODE | ADDRESS        | ZoneA | ZoneB |
 --------------------------------------------------
 | 01 | SW1 ABC  | 1 Street, city | 1     | 1     |
 | 02 | SW1 DEF  | 2 Street, city | 0     | 1     |
 | 03 | SW2 ABC  | 3 Street, city | 1     | 0     |
 | 04 | SW3 XYZ  | 4 Street, city | 1     | 0     |
```

**SOLUTUION**

```
SELECT addr.*, 
IF(a.ZoneRef is null ,'N','Y') as inZoneA_Y_N, 
IF(b.ZoneRef is null ,'N','Y') as inZoneB_Y_N
FROM addresses AS addr
LEFT JOIN ZoneA AS a on addr.postcode = a.postcode 
LEFT JOIN ZONEB AS b on addr.postcode = b.postcode
WHERE
addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT a.postcode 
    FROM ZoneA AS a
    WHERE a.ZoneRef IN
    ('A1','A2','A3','A4')
)
OR addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT b.postcode 
    FROM ZoneB AS b 
    WHERE b.ZoneRef IN 
   ('B1','B2','B3','B4')
)
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample input and output?

Comment: input/output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use IN and LEFT JOIN together, with some 'IF' statements thrown in.

```
SELECT addr.*, 
IF(a.ZoneRef is null ,'N','Y') as inZoneA_Y_N, 
IF(b.ZoneRef is null ,'N','Y') as inZoneB_Y_N
FROM addresses AS addr
LEFT JOIN ZoneA AS a on addr.postcode = a.postcode 
LEFT JOIN ZONEB AS b on addr.postcode = b.postcode
WHERE
addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT a.postcode 
    FROM ZoneA AS a
    WHERE a.ZoneRef IN
    ('A1','A2','A3','A4')
)
OR addr.postcode IN (
    SELECT b.postcode 
    FROM ZoneB AS b 
    WHERE b.ZoneRef IN 
   ('B1','B2','B3','B4')
)
```

Comment: If you do a `LEFT JOIN` are you sure to need to do sub search as you already have the result with the first request ? I think your `WHERE` may be like : `WHERE a.zoneref IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4')
    OR b.zoneref IN ('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4')` in order to gain time ... If not, I'd like to understand why this is needed.

Comment: What if tomorrow you have new Zone Reference in either one table ?

Comment: I'm using the WHERE to restrict the results from the Zone tables, the 'ZoneRef' values will be dynamic, I've used A1, A2 etc here as an example but in reality every time the query is executed the zoneref's will change. it may be A1, A2, A3 one time and A10, A44, A98 the next.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a `LEFT JOIN` on your SQL request like this :

```
SELECT addr.*, a.postcode as ExistZoneA, b.postcode as ExistZoneB
FROM addresses AS addr 
LEFT JOIN ZoneA AS a
    ON addr.postcode = a.postcode
LEFT JOIN ZoneB AS b
    ON addr.postcode = b.postcode
WHERE a.zoneref IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4')
    OR b.zoneref IN ('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4')
```

Then you can check if there is a value on ExistZoneA and ExistZoneB

Comment: I'll lend you some inverted commas and opening brackets.

Comment: Never worked with so many joins. How does this work? First all join operations take place and then the selection, right? :O Confused. In what order will join take place?

Comment: Sorry for the opening bracket, I did it a little too fast. But I don't see inverted commas ? @MathewsMathai for more information about JOIN, you can check [w3school article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). The join are set in the order you call it. In that example, you will have addresses joined with ZoneA joined with ZoneB. The important part is if you use a "Right, Inner or Left" JOIN. In your example you want all the addresses result so the left table is the most important : LEFT JOIN will show all result of Adresses, even if there is no data associated in ZoneA nor ZoneB

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. I didn't know that we could use `address.column` and `ZoneA.column` columns from Join result. I thought it becomes a new table and cannot he accessed using original table names. So, that's new knowledge. :D

Comment: You're welcome :P. If you think my answer is complete, please check it as right :) Have fun manipulating your data

Comment: I feel like this is almost right, but I don't want to return *all* addresses, I want to return only those in ZoneA or ZoneB (or both)

Comment: Can you explain with an exemple of data ? I'm not sure to get your question, but it certainly is a supplement clause on the WHERE requirement. Is this what you want : `WHERE (a.zoneref IN (A1, A2, A3, A4)
    OR b.zoneref IN (B1, B2, B3, B4)) AND (ExistZoneA IS NOT NULL OR ExistZoneA IS NOT NULL)`. If so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've added example data - the 'addresses' table is over 28 million rows, I want to return only those which have postcodes that appear in ZoneA or ZoneB, where the ZoneA or ZoneB 'zoneref' matches the values in the subqueries.  My original code does this, but I have no indication of which Zones the address appears in.

Comment: Well, sorry but seeing your exemple, I am more confused. Is A1 a value ? If it is a value, then you'll have to put it like this `('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'). You said 'ZoneA' = table of Zone references (unique) but it is not unique ? So you may have an ID elsewhere in ZoneA table ?

Comment: Yes, A1 is a value and should be wrapped in quotes. You are correct on the 'unique' thing, the postcode is unique - it will only appear once in a 'Zone' table, but the zoneref may appear multiple times.  I will edit my question to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below,

```
select a.*, 
if(za.REF is null ,'N','Y') as ZoneA_Y_N, 
if(zb.REF is null ,'N','Y') as ZoneB_Y_N 
from addresses a left join ZoneA za on a.POSTCODE = za.POSTCODE 
left join ZoneB zb on a.POSTCODE = zb.POSTCODE
where (za.REF is not null  or zb.REF is not null);
```

Try This [Demo](http://rextester.com/ISROT78602) too.

I hope this will solve you problem

Comment: the 'if' statements here are very useful, I combined those with my original query and go what I needed

Comment: If you solve the problem, then please answer your own question with your query.